# Could not resolve com.android.support:design:27.0.3

Tags: android, android-studio

I can't build a project with Android 27 as target SDK and 27.0.3 as buildToolsVersion.

My Android studio version is 3.0.1 and I also have google() in my repositories in project's buid.gradle.

I get this error:

```
 > Could not resolve com.android.support:design:27.0.3.
> Failed to download SHA1 for resource 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/design/27.0.3/design-27.0.3.pom'.
      > For input string: "<!"
```

Comment: use 27.0.2 for successful build

Comment: same thing happens with 27.0.2

Answer (score 18):

Because of there isn't `27.0.3`, you can use `27.0.1`,`27.0.2`,`27.1.0` instead. You can check the valid revision on [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html).

Answer (score 0):

**As per now use 27.0.2**

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.packagename"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
implementation 'com.android.support:design:'27.0.2'
```

Comment: make sure u use android studio 3.0.1 with kindly 
put : (only implementation for all your gradle files)
implementation 'com.android.support:design:'27.0.2'

dont put:
compile 'com.android.support:design:'27.0.2' (since compile has been depriciated)

Answer (score 0):

Try  this code:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rokolabs.app.rokostickers"
        minSdkVersion 19 // use 19 only use for transition(21)
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 117
        versionName "0.1.30"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
```